# Two ubuntu boxes w/ AMD graphics different glxgears framerates

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

I have two Ubuntu boxes, one 16.04 with AMD GPU DRI_PRIME and one 16.10 with AMD APU.

On the dedicated GPU glxgears has a framerate of around 6000 dropping to over 300 when running fullscreen and CSS has 117fps.

On the APU glxgears has always a framerate of 60 and CSS has only 50fps: Why is that glxgears does not scale?

Comment: I do not know what is `AMD GPU DRI_PRIME`. But glxgears is showing 60 fps because vertical sync is on. It is normal.

Comment: thanks `vblank_mode=0 glxgears` is doing the trick: 3200 fps and over 300 fps in fullscreen. BTW: DRI_PRIME is the environment variable that activates my hybrid notebook GPU for more speed! The better benchmark seems to be CSS, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Pilot6: vertical sync was on and is disabled for AMD APU with command:
`vblank_mode=0 glxgears`